# Decomposition of $x^T K x$ as $y^T y$

Tags: matrix-decomposition

When $x$ is a vector of size Nx1, and $K$ is a very large symmetric sparse matrix of size NxN (say N=100K), is it possible to decompose $x^T K x$ as $y^T y$?

As if I could get $y = K^{1/2} x$.

---

**Edit** for more information:

K is a correlation matrix, where only local correlation is assumed. So it is more a band matrix, as the correlation between variables too far away are assumed to be 0, hence the sparse matrix.

Then, I have a model for which $x$ is the solution I get. And I would like to get the contribution of each variable, meaning I would basically like to get the $y_i^2$'s.

Comment: Does K happen to be positive semidefinite?

Comment: $x^T K x > 0$, but I actually don't know if it would be true for all possible $x$.

Comment: A little extra information could be really helpful to come up with a useful solution. Where does $K$ come from? Why are you doing this?

Comment: @eric_kernfeld Please see my edit.

Comment: That's interesting and useful. What does your model say? I am wondering about the interpretation of $y$, because it seems like the solution will not be unique. You could potentially get very different conclusions depending on a detail that seems unimportant based on the information provided so far. For instance, Cholesky decomposition as suggested below can be done in many different ways depending on the permutation selected. Another option, eigendecomposition, would give still a different $y$. This really might be unworkable statistically even once you do manage to compute it efficiently.

Comment: Given your edit, I agree with @eric_kernfeld. This may be a so-called "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)". If you can take a step back and explain your goal, you will likely get better answers. (Most likely a partial eigendecomposition can address your problem, but more details are needed.)

Comment: The model is described in https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.04.28.066720. It is not easy to described in a couple of sentences. There, I'm calling $\beta^T R \beta$ what I'm calling $x^T K x$ here, and this corresponds to the total heritability captured by the genetic variants I have. I would like to get the individual contribution of each genetic variant to this heritability.

Answer (score 3):

[Cholesky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) decomposition should work. It will factor $K=LL^T$, similar conceptually to a square root of a matrix. So that $y^T=L^Tx$

There is software that takes advantage of sparsity to compute Cholesky decompositions more economically. For instance, the function `Cholesky` in the R package `Matrix`:

http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/Matrix/html/Cholesky.html

Comment: Ok, but can I really get a Cholesky decomposition of a matrix that is that large?

Comment: how sparse is your matrix @F.Privé?

Comment: Does Cholesky work if $K$ is not positive semidefinite? It seems this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld, needs to be positive definite

Comment: (+1; $LDL^T$ is the obvious way to go.) @eric_kernfeld: All eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real, by definition $K$ is symmetric so that is covered. Strictly speaking Cholesky does not work for PSD but only for PD. That's why the $LDL^T$. :D

Comment: @usεr11852 but doesn't $K = LDT^T$ not quite work because that leaves us with $x^TKx = (L^Tx)^TDL^Tx$, which cannot be written as $y^Ty$? Also, we don't even know that $K$ is PSD, right? The OP didn't mention that. It could be indefinite or even negative definite for all we know, in which case $LDT^T$ is not possible

Comment: @JakeWestfall: Maybe I misunderstand something: 1. $D$ is diagonal... Taking the square root of it is trivial. (And of course, the transpose of the diagonal matrix $D$ is the matrix $D$). 2. A symmetric matrix, $K=K^T$, has only real eigenvalues. Sure, it can be PSD and not only PD but that's why the $LDL^T$. (And of course $L$ does not have to be sparse any more.) Again apologies if I misinterpreter something here; I really value your posts.

Comment: What if $D$ has some negative values? You'd end up with imaginary parts to the result. I have never studied complex-valued Cholesky decompositions; I guess it might work though.

Comment: @Aksakal I added a sentence about available software. Feel free to revert my edit if you don't want to cover that.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld: If $K$ positive semi-definite, then the pivots are non-negative.

Comment: That's why I asked OP where $K$ came from and whether $K$ is PSD, but it seems there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: @Aksakal The matrix is more a band matrix where each position away from e.g. 1000 is non-zero, and further away is 0. But that makes it a very sparse matrix overall.
Does cholesky give a sparse matrix also?

Comment: @F.Privé, yes, look at example on page 12.25 http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/133A/lectures/chol.pdf after permutations chol factor becomes very sparse

Comment: Thanks @usεr11852 :) I see the mistake in my reasoning now

Comment: @Aksakal I've just tried `Matrix::Cholesky()` and it says it is not positive definite, which is not surprising to me.